# String numeric input with magnitude to integer

Tags: python

Is there an existing library that would convert variable user input into an integer? User input can also have a magnitude suffix "K, M, G"

```
K-1000
M-1000000
G-1000000000

Input String -> Integer
"22.5" -> 22
"22.5K" -> 22500
"1,234" -> 1234
"1,234M" -> 1234000000
"0.1G" -> 100000000
"1.234E3" -> 1234000
```

Comment: For a simple version, maybe `int(string.replace('K', '000').replace('M', '000000').replace('G', '000000000'))`. Obviously this doesn’t satisfy all of the conditions.

Comment: Give a try to `humanfriendly`  package : https://pypi.org/project/humanfriendly/ For example if you do `num = humanfriendly.parse_size('16G')` then num should be 16000000000.  Hope it helps.

Comment: for string of sort  `"123e7"` (doesn't matter if it's capitol e) you can use  `eval("123E7")` and get it as an integer